# Is this calculation executed in Python?

Tags: python, python-internals

> Disclaimer: I'm new to programming, but new to Python. This may be a pretty basic question.

I have the following block of code:

```
for x in range(0, 100):
    y = 1 + 1;
```

Is the calculation of `1 + 1` in the second line executed 100 times?

I have two suspicions why it might not:

1) The compiler sees `1 + 1` as a constant value, and thus compiles this line into `y = 2;`.

2) The compiler sees that `y` is only set and never referenced, so it omits this line of code.

Are either/both of these correct, or does it actually get executed each iteration over the loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option 1 is executed; the CPython compiler simplifies mathematical expressions with constants in the peephole optimiser.

Python will not eliminate the loop body however.

You can introspect what Python produces by looking at the bytecode; use the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to take a look:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f():
...     for x in range(100):
...         y = 1 + 1
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              26 (to 29)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3          19 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             25 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   28 POP_BLOCK
        >>   29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

The bytecode at position 19, `LOAD_CONST` loads the value `2` to store in `y`.

You can see the constants associated with the code object in the `co_consts` attribute of a code object; for functions you can find that object under the `__code__` attribute:

```
>>> f.__code__.co_consts
(None, 100, 1, 2)
```

`None` is the default return value for any function, `100` the literal passed to the `range()` call, `1` the original literal, left in place by the peephole optimiser and `2` is the result of the optimisation.

The work is done in [`peephole.c`, in the `fold_binops_on_constants()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1addc4f0f10c/Python/peephole.c#l77):

```c
/* Replace LOAD_CONST c1. LOAD_CONST c2 BINOP
   with    LOAD_CONST binop(c1,c2)
   The consts table must still be in list form so that the
   new constant can be appended.
   Called with codestr pointing to the first LOAD_CONST.
   Abandons the transformation if the folding fails (i.e.  1+'a').
   If the new constant is a sequence, only folds when the size
   is below a threshold value.  That keeps pyc files from
   becoming large in the presence of code like:  (None,)*1000.
*/
```

Take into account that Python is a highly dynamic language, such optimisations can only be applied to literals and constants that you cannot later dynamically replace.

Comment: I'm assuming it would, however, not compile into a constant if this were made a function, and the value is passed in as an argument? `loopAdd(1, 1);`

Comment: @JeradRose: no, because you cannot know what `loopAdd()` is bound to at runtime. You can *replace* just about anything in Python.

Comment: Awesome detailed answer. Thanks!